# React save old URL before route redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am currently using the following code to check if the user is authenticated to allow them to a specific page and if they are not, to redirect them to the login page.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={
            (props) => authenticated === "false" ? <Redirect to='/login' /> : <Component {...props} />
        }
    />
)

export default AuthRoute
```

The implementation above works as it should. However, I was wondering if it is possible to preserve the old url, the one before the redirect to `/login` - lets say an user, that is not logged in, attempts to access `/posts` which is protected and gets redirected to the `/login` page.

What I want to do is to redirect the user to the page, prior to the `/login`, `/posts`, after successful authentication

Is such implementation possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Redirect` component `to` prop can receive `string` or `object` so your auth route can look like this:

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, authenticated, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={
            (props) => authenticated === "false" ? <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login' state: { from: props.location }}} /> : <Component {...props} />
        }
    />
)
```

And then in your login component you can access that state as:

```
const { from } = this.props.location.state;
```

[Here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect/to-object) is documentation for `Redirect`.